# Google Sheets IMPORTXML XPATH query failure

Tags: xpath, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

Xpath for Google Sheets IMPORTXML query doesn't seem to work:

```
//*[@id="itempagetradegraphcontainer"]/div/div[1]/div/div/table/tr[56]/td[3]
```

Link: https://merchos.net/app/item.php?id=1215

Comment: When you say it doesn't work, what results are you seeing?

Comment: It Says N/A Import content empty